# Doctrine Gedmo Nested Tree : change a node's parent

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a tree already existing and I need to change some node's parent.
Let's say I have the following tree :

```
/Food
    /Vegetables
        /Onions
        /Carrots
        /Cabbages
        /Potatoes
    /Fruits
```

If I execute

```
$Potatoes->setParent($Onions);
$repo->verify();
```

this error is thrown : `node [x] right is greater than parent's [n] right value`

If I execute

```
$repo->persistAsFirstChildOf($Potatoes, $Onions);
$repo->verify();
```

this error is thrown : `node [x] has invalid left or right values`

So maybe am I missing a specific function

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `$repo->_em->flush();` before calling `$repo->verify()`;